# Right Justified Zero filled String in C

Tags: c, string, string-formatting

I want to right justify a string value with zero filled on left hand side. I have written following code but it prints white space instead of 0.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
            char s[4]="PJ";
            printf("%04s",s);
    }

    Output: "  PJ"

    I need output as "00PJ".
```

Comment: The zero is in the format specification is only for numerical output, not strings. You have to add that yourself manually. Using the zero for non-numerical types is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
#define MIN_LEN 4

if (strlen(s) < MIN_LEN) {
    printf("%0*d%s", MIN_LEN-(int)strlen(s), 0, s);
}
else {
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Don't forget to include `<string.h>`

**Edit :**
To explain our discussion about buffer overflow, just try this piece of code :

```
int main()
{
  struct 
  {
    char s[4];
    int i;
  } test;

  test.i = 0x12345678;

  strcpy(test.s,"PJHA");
  printf("Output =%s\nTest =%x",test.s,test.i);

}
```

Output :

```
Output =PJHA
Test =12345600
```

If you change the size to `5`, the code is corrected and the stack following your string is not corrupted.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but I am trying someway using memset to reduce the line of codes.

Comment: Please check my answer and suggest if anything wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Note: If the 4 in OP's `s[4]` is tied to the 4 in `"%04s`, then `strlen(s) < MIN_LEN` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the short line code answer for my question:-
This will take care of any length of input variable like `s = "J", s="JH", s="JHA", s="PJHA"`
and corresponding output will be `"000J", "00JH", "0JHA", "PJHA"` .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
        char s[4],s2[4];
        strcpy(s,"JH");
        sprintf(s2,"%04s",s);
        memset(s2,'0',4-(int)strlen(s));
        printf("Output =%s\n",s2);

}
Output =00JH
```

Comment: maybe `char s[5],s2[5];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes we can use size `5` also for last null character. In both cases above solution will work.

Comment: `In both cases above solution will work.` case of `s="PJHA"` ?

Comment: Yes @BLUEPIXY is right, the size **MUST** be `5`. If not, "PJHA" will produce a buffer overflow and your program _can_ randomly crash.

Comment: @Michael and @BLYEPIXY at my side , its running with `s="PJHA"` also. No buffer error. Are you seeing any error at your system ?

Comment: @CodeCodeCode, there is a buffer overflow. `strcpy` write `0` on the byte following the 4 bytes of `s` on the stack. I edit my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the above simpler solution while giving an alternative more **manual** one:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void print(char *s, int ncount)
{
    if(s == NULL) return;
    int len = strlen(s);
    if(len > ncount) printf("%s", s);
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < ncount - len; ++i)
            printf("0");
        printf("%s", s);
    }
}
int main()
{

    char s[4]="PJ";
    print(s, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @lulyon. But do you really think we need that much line of code for a small task? Please check my answer.

Comment: That is OK. I've considered that too, it doesn't surprise me. I think  @Michael 's answer is outstanding and brings something new for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char s[5]="PJ";
    char padding[sizeof(s)] = {0};
    int width = sizeof(padding)-1;

    memset(padding, '0', width);
    width -= strlen(s);

    //printf("%.*s%s\n", (int)(4-strlen(s)), "0000", s);
    printf("%.*s%s\n", width, padding, s);
    return 0;
}
```